# Only show users in the same group as the logged in user

Tags: drupal, view, organic-groups

I am using drupal and want to make a view only to show the users in a the same group as the current user.

I have a view currently showing all users, but I can't get it to auto filter by logged in user. i'm assuming it'll be some sort of conditional filter/relationship

Any help is appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, in your view, go to '**Page Settings**' section and you will see '**Access**' field. You can set **Permission** to your view or you can also set '**Role**' meaning who actually should see the view output.